# Xpath works perfectly in browser console but returns NULL in Python Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape:

```
https://www.example.com
```

When I try the Xpath in browser console:

```
> $x('//div[@id="uat-dropdown-container-dosage"]/div/span/text()')[0]
> "200 mg"
```

But when I try the same in scrapy:

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="uat-dropdown-container-dosage"]/div/span/text()')
```

It doesn't return anything, if I try to do this:

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="uat-dropdown-container-dosage"]/div/span/text()')[0]
List Index out of range Error!
```

I don't understand why it isn't working?

Comment: please let us know what is in response. It's not uncommon for sites to try to not serve the (same) content to scrapers

Comment: The response is 200, do you want to have a look at response.body ?

Comment: please share your code so we can reproduce what you are seeing. I'd look first at what the contents is of what you are getting back from the site indeed.. (please not that a site could return 200 but some message that content is not available in your region/bot/etc. )

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#caveats-with-inspecting-the-live-browser-dom

Comment: @Chrisvdberge So it turns out that the problem is with the website. They introduced JavaScript, therefore the page did get a response of 200 but the proxy service provider that I use did not provide JavaScript rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Please open the source of the start_urls using ctrl/cmd + U, you may be unable to find these classes, which results in empty response and thus you are not getting your desired results. Please share the `URL` of the site so I can have a look.

Comment: Hi, so the Xpaths are working but the problem is that the website has introduced JavaScript which I did not render. So it returns None/Empty list from the Xpaths.

Comment: Yes, exactly you need to come up with other technique.